# Format date in Vaadin date picker

Tags: java, vaadin-date-picker

I'm using Vaadin Date picker 3.3.0

In Java, I set locale as the below code.

`datePicker.setLocale(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);`

But the date format display is YYYY-MM-dd.

How to format it to: YYYY/MM/dd ??
Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can post a minimal code sample?

Answer (score 3):

The only way right now to influence the date format of the date picker by using the Java API is to use the locale (like you do).

There is a feature request for setting a date format manually (like `datePicker.setDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");`), maybe you want to give a thumb up on that feature request so that they will implement this soon: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker-flow/issues/156

Also in the comments of that feature request, there is described an alternative approach on how to set a date format manually by not using the Java API, but using JavaScript. Maybe you want to give it a try: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker-flow/issues/156#issuecomment-603904954